# How to call child View method from parent View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Here is a Child View - Marionette ItemView, and parent presented by Marionette CompositeView!
I tried use Backbone.babysitter, but without results

```js
var CheckboxView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: JST["components-checkboxItem"],
  className: "checkbox",
  ui: {
    "checkbox": "#checkbox-item"
  },

  selectAll: function () {
    //do some stuff here (this method should be called from parent)
  }
});

module.exports = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  className: 'multiselect',
  template: JST["components-multiselect"],
  childView: CheckboxView,
  childViewContainer: ".checkboxes",

  events: {
    "click .selectAll": "selectAll",
  },
  
  selectAll: function () {
    //I need to call appropriate child method from here!!!
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to invoke it like:

`this.children.call("selectAll",1,2);` or

`this.children.apply("selectAll",[1,2]);` from CompositeView.

You can find more info at [backbone.babysitter](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter) which is what marionette is using to handle this

Comment: @T J, one more question, how can I put an argument into this call?
`this.children.call("selectAll");`

Comment: @Arsenowitch the syntax is `container.call("doStuff", 1, 2);` where 1,2 are arguments. marionette uses [babsitter](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter) in this case children is our `container`

Comment: Thank you!
I found the documentation about babysitter.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer iterate children:

```
this.children.each(function (itemView) {
    itemView.selectAll(args)
});
```

Comment: Of course. IMHO it's clearer when you see method and arguments in code, so just another way.